# I need confirmation about my understanding on IQueryable & IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable, iqueryable

**IQueryable** 
From my understanding, In LINQ to SQL & Object , until I execute my query, I can add more expressions.

In this example, query1 and Query2 become final query when I try to execute Query2. Am I right?
Or I am right if 'Numbers' was a DB?

```
    int[] Numbers= new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    IQueryable<int> Query1 = from X in Numbers.AsQueryable()
                             where X > 1
                             select X;
    IQueryable<int> Query2 = from X in Query1
                             where X > 2
                             select X;
    //if I do this: Query2.Count() -> before it executes this, those two queries become one query (FinalQuery)?
    IQueryable<int> FinalQuery = from X in Query2
                                 where X > 2
                                 select X;
```

But, if I would use IEnumerable, Would it execute Query1 and get a IEnumerable. Then it would execute Query2 and get the final IEnumerable? ; Would it execute 2 queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I would use IEnumerable, Would it excute Query1 and get a IEnumerable. Then It would excute Query2 and get the final IEnumerable?

Yes. But they will be executed in tandem, each number `X` will 'flow' through both queries. That is called 'lazy evaluation' or 'deferred execution'.

> Would it excute 2 querys ?

Yes. Overlapping in time.

> [Using IQueryable] befor it excute this, those two querys become one query (FinalQuery)?

No.

Exactly the same thing will happen with `IQueryable<>` as with `IEnumerable<>`. There is no 'smart' component involved that will optimize `where X > 1` away.

Answer (score 1):

Neither IEnumerable nor IQueryable LINQ queries will execute until you try to actually use the result. They're both just classes containing extension methods of the same names. But they are both 'lazy' in that they return new queries, not actual results.

The general difference is that IEnumerable is using Funcs (essentially delegates) as the underlying storage of the query, whereas the IQueryable is using Expression Trees (so that the query can be 'translated' to SQL for example).

Comment: I didnt say that it will excute befor I use the result. Look at the example and see I write a line -> Query2.Count(). so I asked if the 2 querys become one query  - Final query. Am I right?

Comment: @StavAlfi I don't quite understand. Running Query2.Count() will give you an int result, but will not change Query2 in any way, since they are immutable. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Im having hard time to understand my self. Im sory for wasting your time. I hope some one else will understand. Thank you for your time agian.

Comment: @Erix I think what is being asked is whether the result of the `FinalQuery` expression is different if Query 2 is executed (like .ToList) before the final query line is reached

Comment: When q2 is excuted,does it translated to something like finalQuery and then to SQL?